# Installing Patches To SharePoint 2013 and Downtime

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, patching, upgrade-sharepoint

I have an inquiry about SharePoint 2013 patches, if I install below mentioned SharePoint 2013 pathces on **production farm servers** (Application and Front-Ends), will it require a downtime? as we need to re-run the configuration wizard in order for the upgrade to take place. and it may affect the sites hosted by this SharePoint farm.

Patches are:
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable

Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x64)

Microsoft Access Services Server 2013 x64

Microsoft Excel Services Components 2013 x64

Microsoft Office PowerPoint Services 2013 x64

Microsoft Word Server 2013 x64

Microsoft SharePoint Portal 2013 x64

Microsoft Shared Components 2013 x64

Microsoft Slide Library 2013 x64

Microsoft Web Analytics 2013 x64

Microsoft InfoPath Forms Services 2013 x64

Microsoft SharePoint Multilingual Solutions 2013 x64

Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 x64

Microsoft Education 2013 x64

Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (x64)

Microsoft InfoPath Forms Services 2013 x64

Microsoft SharePoint Multilingual Solutions 2013 x64

Microsoft Slide Library 2013 x64

PerformancePoint Services For SharePoint 2013 x64

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 Core x64

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 Core x64

Microsoft Web Analytics 2013 x64

Microsoft Office PowerPoint Services 2013 x64

Microsoft Visio Services 2013 x64

Microsoft Word Server 2013 x64

PerformancePoint Services For SharePoint 2013 x64

Microsoft Education 2013 x64

Microsoft SharePoint Multilingual Solutions 2013 x64

Microsoft Access Services Server 2013 x64

Microsoft Slide Library 2013 x64

Microsoft InfoPath Forms Services 2013 x64

Microsoft Office PowerPoint Services 2013 x64

Microsoft Shared Components 2013 x64

Microsoft Web Analytics 2013 x64

Microsoft Excel Services Components 2013 x64

Microsoft Word Server 2013 x64

Microsoft Visio Services 2013 x64

Microsoft Excel Services Components 2013 x64

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 Core x64

Microsoft Shared Components 2013 x64

Microsoft SharePoint Portal 2013 x64

These patches should be tested and staged as well, before installing them on a production farm to ensure there's nothing went wrong at the application/site level, right ?

Your kind help and advice are appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Will it require a downtime?**

Of course, **Yes**, it will require!

In SharePoint 2013/2010/2007, Running the `SharePoint Configuration Wizard` will require **downtime** even you have high availability environment.

> **Note:** The zero downtime patching has been introduced In SharePoint 2016, but you must have high availability environment to perform it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Moahmmed, much appreciated. do you have any idea how long the downtime is going to be? let's suppose we have a farm that contains 10 sharepoint servers (4 Application and 6 web front ends) , I believe the downtime will not be less than 6 hours. am i right ?

Comment: Actually, In SharePoint patching, I don't think there is anyone who can specify **exactly** how long the downtime is going to be? because It depends on a lot of factors (not only number of servers),

Comment: But as a best practice if you have a staging (identical prod farm) environment you should apply the patch on it first. this is will give you a near measure for how long the downtime is going to be? also if it applied successfully on staging this will ensure there is no issue to apply the same patch on production. moreover, it will minimize the risk and the time on prod because you have learned from the issues that may face you on staging!

Comment: If you don't have a staging environment it's heavily recommended to apply it first on the test environment before going to the prod, also schedule to apply the patch out working hour or in the weekend with minimum outage 4-6 hours approximately that may be extended or not based on your current situation needs!